# can I provide and reference services in the same component when use declarative services for osgi?

Tags: java, components, service, osgi, declarative

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="sensor_test">
   <implementation class="test.sensor.version1.serviceImpl.SensorServiceImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="test.sensor.version1.serviceInterface.SensorServiceInterface"/>
   </service>
   <reference bind="setOntologyService" cardinality="0..1" interface="test.ontology.version1.serviceinterface.OntologyServiceInterface" name="OntologyServiceInterface" policy="dynamic" unbind="unsetOntologyService"/>
</scr:component>`

For what is showed above, is that OK to provide and reference services in the same component?
For example, there are two bundles A and B. A provides a service for B to use, and B also provides a service for A to use. What should I do with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be perfectly fine because the service reference is both optional and dynamic.

If you define a circular dependency where the references are both mandatory, then DS will report an error. There has to be a way to create one component first, and with mandatory references neither component can be created until the other is created (however, a third bundle "C" could register a service that satisfies one of the components).

With an optional/dynamic reference, DS can construct one component with the reference unbound, then construct the other component and inject it back into the first.